# Why is run() method called twice for running the test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

Consider the following Python code from Kent Beck's book [Test Driven Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) *Chapter 18* where he is building a framework for unit testing.

```
class TestCaseTest(TestCase):
    def testRunning(self):
       test= WasRun("testMethod")
       assert(not test.wasRun)
       test.run() // Here run() is called once
       assert(test.wasRun)
  TestCaseTest("testRunning").run()//Here run() is called again
```

The implementation of the base class `TestCase` looks like the following:

```
TestCase
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name= name
def  run(self):
    method = getattr(self, self.name)
    method()
```

1. Why is `run()` method called twice in the above code snippet?
2. And who is calling the method `testRunning()` and when? Here it is only defining the method but no one seems to be calling this method.

P.S: I come from a Java background and I am not much familiar with Python syntax as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the book you're talking about, so I'm going off the code snippet you posted.

It looks like run() methods on two different objects are being called -- one of class TestCaseTest, one of class WasRun (or whatever a function named WasRun returns).

As for who is calling testRunning(), .run() is called on the TestCaseTest object and this is presumably a method from the superclass TestCase. Look up run() in TestCase and see whether self.testRunning() is called there.

Comment: I have added the code for the base class for your perusal. It seems like I understand it now. The last line in the run method is the key.

Comment: Okay, so there a method is retrieved and run based on the attribute self.name. Which method is run would depend on how the TestCase was initialized, if self.name is "hello", then the method called is self.hello(). Glad to hear it makes sense to you in context.

Comment: BTW is this mechanism called *pluggable selector* in Python?

Comment: That seems like the name of the pattern, but I'm not sure I would say it's called that "in Python". This seems like a technique from JUnit that was then also used in the Python version of JUnit. It's not something you see often in idiomatic Python code.